# Please help me replace some javascript with html output

Tags: javascript, mailchimp

I have a Mailchimp email sign up form on my page. When a successful or failed sign up happens it grabs a success/failure message from a javascript library.

I want to stop it grabbing the default messages (which I cant edit as I believe they live on Mailchimp's servers) and replace them with my own. Can you help?

Here is the relevant function:

```
function mce_success_cb(resp){
$('#mce-success-response').hide();
$('#mce-error-response').hide();
if (resp.result=="success"){
    $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
    $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(resp.msg);
    $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').each(function(){
        this.reset();
    });
} else {
    var index = -1;
    var msg;
    try {
        var parts = resp.msg.split(' - ',2);
        if (parts[1]==undefined){
            msg = resp.msg;
        } else {
            i = parseInt(parts[0]);
            if (i.toString() == parts[0]){
                index = parts[0];
                msg = parts[1];
            } else {
                index = -1;
                msg = resp.msg;
            }
        }
    } catch(e){
        index = -1;
        msg = resp.msg;
    }
    try{
        if (index== -1){
            $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
            $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);            
        } else {
            err_id = 'mce_tmp_error_msg';
            html = '<div id="'+err_id+'" style="'+err_style+'"> '+msg+'</div>';

            var input_id = '#mc_embed_signup';
            var f = $(input_id);
            if (ftypes[index]=='address'){
                input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index]+'-addr1';
                f = $(input_id).parent().parent().get(0);
            } else if (ftypes[index]=='date'){
                input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index]+'-month';
                f = $(input_id).parent().parent().get(0);
            } else {
                input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index];
                f = $().parent(input_id).get(0);
            }
            if (f){
                $(f).append(html);
                $(input_id).focus();
            } else {
                $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
                $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);
            }
        }
    } catch(e){
        $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
        $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that anywhere you see something like this:

`$('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);`

you want to replace the msg part with your relevant text depending on where in the logic you are. So the first one (line 6) in the code you posted, is the success = true, so replace

`$('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(resp.msg);`

with something like

`$('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html('Successfully signed up');`

Comment: Thank you so much Prescott! That worked perfectly. You've made a Javascript uber noob very happy.